# JavaScript: Reading String into dynamically created array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating and adding an array of input text boxes to the DOM in pure JavaScript. This works fine. Then, later on in the code I want to load a file and input the first line of string data from the file into each of the array elements. I can load the file and extract the string, but I can’t seem to add the values to the array. Since the array is dynamically created, I can’t use document.getElementBy Id() etc in order to confirm or append the data.

```
var row0 = new Array(9);  // declared as global variable; 
//successfully instantiated and added to DOM earlier on in the code

…

function loadFileAsText(){
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        var result = textFromFileLoaded.substring(0,8); // works    
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; ++i){
            row0[i].value = result [i]; // not working              
        }        
};
```

How would I get this to work?

Comment: declare var result = new Array(8);

Comment: Are you sure the code is runtimeerror free so far? I can't tell where you're initializing any `row[i]` with an object that has an `value` attribute (you're assigning a value to it). Further, what might be the cause of your problem could be, that `row0` is out of scope: `loadFilesAsText()` has no acces to it. (Use a debugger to be sure that this is not the problem.) Besides: better use `row0 = [];` and `row0.push(...)` (my opinion).

Comment: "`// declared as global variable`": this definitively depends on the rest of the code / the code around (if it's really in global scope).

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have fixed the array length issue. I guess try-catch-finally is correct about row0 not being in scope. If row0 does not reside within the HTML code, how can I get a handle on it? I tried document.getElementById("row0" + [i]).value = result[i]; within the for-loop but this did not work either. I'm fairly new to JavaScript - apologies for asking questions that may seem obvious.

Comment: Variable declaration and usage should be in the same scope which can be accomplished by (1) putting them in to a (wrapper) function or (2) by binding the valiable to the window object (discouraged). 1: `(function(){ /* declare variable and handler */ ... /* attach handler */  })()` or, instead of ad-hoc running the closure, put it into an onload handler (`$(function(){ ... })` in jQuery). 2: `window.row0 = []; ... window.row0.push(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Fix the for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; ++i){
            row0[i] = {};
            row0[i].value = result [i]; // not working              
        }
```